# Exporting html input to excel/csv

Tags: html, node.js, excel, csv, export

I'm looking to create a logging system, but I'm not sure where to start. Could you please point me in the correct way.

I'm looking to create a bootstrapped html page that collects data from an input.
This input should have 4 "columns" or "cells". This data needs to be "pushed" into a csv file to be downloaded at a click or get live updated.

Could anyone point me to a tutorial or docs where I could learn how to do this?

I usually work with Node.JS.
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: which part did you not understand ? the post data from client to backend ? the save data to csv ? export csv ? you should break it down and work your way first to last and search around on here,  there are some packages that can help u as well such as https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv#readme

Comment: if you don't know how to make logging mechanism this article was very usefull to me https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-logging-tutorial/